# How can I make a custom NSWindow subclass into a custom NSPanel?

Tags: objective-c, macos, inheritance, osx-lion, nswindow

I'm using a very complex custom subclass of NSWindow called `MyWindow`. Now I want to make a new class called `MyPanel` which has the same behavior as NSPanel, but which inherits from `MyWindow` as it's superclass. I've read the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingPanels.html) for `NSPanel` but it doesn't say how to make a panel from custom NSWindow subclasses. My current code:

MyPanel.h

```
#import "MyWindow.h"

@interface MyPanel : MyWindow

- (BOOL)isFloatingPanel;
- (void)setFloatingPanel:(BOOL)flag;
- (BOOL)becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded;
- (void)setBecomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded:(BOOL)flag;
- (BOOL)worksWhenModal;
- (void)setWorksWhenModal:(BOOL)flag;

@end
```

MyPanel.m

```
#import "MyPanel.h"

@implementation MyPanel

@end
```

So now how can I accomplish this without directly subclassing `NSPanel` (which would mean I'd have to copy and paste all the code from `MyWindow` to `MyPanel`)? What methods, delegates, properties do I have to recreate/implement to get the same behavior as an NSPanel?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already answered the question yourself. NSPanel is a subclass of NSWindow, so instead of subclassing NSWindow you should subclass NSPanel.  That being said.. If you're careful you can create an NSPanel and change its superclass programmatically to an instance of MyWindow.